# last value after comma csv file

Tags: python, csv

How would I go about printing out the last value after comma in a csv file, i want to loop through the file and print out the last values:

Data:

```
20181016135716, 00-00-00-00-00-04, 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.8, 6, 3, 198, 3, 155000000, 3, 198, 3, 155000000, 62.757528
20181016135716, 00-00-00-00-00-04, 10.0.0.8, 10.0.0.1, 6, 2, 132, 3, 123000000, 2, 132, 3, 123000000, 42.267051
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in (list(csv.reader(f))):
        print(', '.join(row)[-1])
```

This only give me the last character 8 and 1

Comment: Try this `print(', '.join(row[-1]))`. Please let me know if it works

Comment: @RockyLi Yes that's what I meant. Just a bit hurry :)

Comment: the output was not what i wanted, but I just did this instead (', '.join(row)[-9:]) and it worked out. Now i can append these values into a list

Comment: @user3768971 your solution (`(', '.join(row)[-9:])` is a complete WTF (you are parsing the csv file to tuples, then "unparsing" them back to strings - you could as well just read the file as a plain text file) and will not get "the last value" but "the last 9 characters", whatever they are, so if the last value append to be a smaller or higher number (anything with more or less than 8 digits and one decimal point) you will get rubbish.  Feliks's answer is the correct one (minus the useless wrapping of `csv.reader()` into a list, cf my comment).

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
  for row in (list(csv.reader(f))):
    print(', '.join(row.split(',')[-1])
```

Basically you are just accessing the last character of the row. But you need to split it with , and then pick the last value

Comment: WTF  day ???  ` list(csv.reader(f))` is useless (readers are iterable) and potentially harmful (it forces load the whole content in memory for no good reason),  `row.split(',')` is not only useless (the whole point of `csv.reader` is to parse the csv so you don't have to do it manually) but will also crash (tuples have no `split()` method), and re-joining the result afterward is just plain useless.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this answer should not be allowed to upvote actually.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are joining the list first and then retrieve the last item of that string, which happens to be the last character. Try parsing it like this instead:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        value = float(row[-1])
        print(value)
```

Comment: ` list(csv.reader(f))` is useless (readers are iterable) and potentially harmful (it forces load the whole content in memory for no good reason). Just use `for row in csv.reader(f)`, this will work just fine and save your memory.

Answer (score -1):

Every answer before answered the question. However, when your csv file will become larger, that way will not be most efficient one. I suggest to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to do it, it is meant for that:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('output.csv', header=None)
print(file.iloc[:, -1])
```

Output will be:

```
0    62.757528
1    42.267051
```

**EDIT**

To answer the comment, I made a benchmark with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import timeit


def without_pandas():
    with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            value = float(row[-1])


def with_pandas():
    file = pd.read_csv('output.csv', header=None)
    for row in file.iloc[:, -1]:
        value = float(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 10000
    print("Without pandas:", timeit.timeit(
        'without_pandas()', number=num,
        setup="from __main__ import without_pandas")/num)
    print("With pandas:", timeit.timeit(
        'with_pandas()', number=num,
        setup="from __main__ import with_pandas")/num)
```

The output is:

```
Without pandas: 0.012996618213300826
With pandas: 0.012586948527599453
```

with a file of exactly 751K (6864 lines), when indeed the efficiency is quite the same for smaller file.

Comment: Panda internally uses the stdlib csv package, so I fail to see how it could be "more efficient". And the csv module's reads the content in chunks, so the file size is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You are right, but I made a benchmark, i edited my answer. Try it to test if I made any mistake. Even if, for smaller file, I think it is better to have values we want in a single list and loop through this list, rather than looping through the all csv to get just the last value of these lines.

Comment: First: use the `timeit` module for such benchmarks (one single iteration is meaningless, you have to run the code hundreds of time and average out the result to compensate for external factors). Second: make sure your functions are functionally equivalent (does `value = file.iloc[:,-1]` iterates on all rows and convert the last row item to a float ???). And finally : DO NOT WRAP THE  `csv.reader` IN A `list` - this force read the whole content in memory for no good reason (and can have a huge impact on the execution time if this make your computer swap).

Comment: FWIW I did a _correct_ benchmark (returning a list of last row items converted to float), same number of lines, copied from the OP's snippet (same lines repeated), and using the timeit module the csv version is consistently almost twice time faster than the panda one.

Comment: I just did it too, and I do not have that results. The difference is not huge but the file I used to benchmark is not even a 1M file. And the mistake I did on your last case was a blind copy from the most upvoted answer, and I completely agree with it